# Ctrl + a not working in 19.04

Tags: shortcuts, 19.04

After updating from 18.04 to 19.04 my `ctrl + a` shortcut jumps to the start of the current line, instead of highlighting all text. How can I change it back?

I have tried to look into the keyboard section with shortcuts in settings. It does not display any shortcuts binded to `ctrl + a`. Neither does it for `ctrl + c` or `ctrl + v`.

Comment: I meant ctrl + a like the title suggests, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: This usually depends on the application, in which one do you experience it? Or is it all applications?

Comment: Yes - visual studio code, intellij, chrome, text editor and terminal